# How to make the content li tag align in first text

Tags: css, listitem

I'm having trouble with my `li` tag. I want my content to be align.
[image]

```
 <ul>       
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
 </ul>
```

---

```
    ul, li {
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul li {
        margin-top: 10px; 
        font-size: 16px; 
        font-weight: 500; 
    }
    ul li:first-child {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    ul li:before {
        content:"\2B58"; 
        font-size: 14px; 
        margin-right: 10px; 
        color: #951D34; 
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
```

Comment: Can u set the before on a height of 100%? Or can u add this: list-style-position: inside;? And maybe use list-style-image: url(/images/list-style-image.png); instead of a before?

Comment: Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/j75Lz0r8/)?

Comment: @Corné it's not duplicate because i'm not using `list-style`. And the link you gave is different from what result I want. Thank you anyway for commenting in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try please the code below:

```
 li {
       padding-left: 35px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
       font-size: 22px;
       color: #000;
       line-height: 150%;
       position: relative;}
.banner_checklist li:before {
      content:"\2B58"; 
      font-size: 14px; 
      color: #f7941d;
      margin-right: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;}
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Its working well. I added `margin-left:20px;` in `ul li` to align in the other content.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add a `display: flex` to `li`

```css
ul li {
  display: flex; // <--- HERE ---<
  margin-top: 10px; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: 500;
}
```